# How to install kmplayer?

Tags: software-installation

I ran the command `sudo apt-get install kmplayer` to install `kmplayer`, but it is showing this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kmplayer
```

Comment: Have you enabled the `universe` repository in your software sources?

Comment: Also what's your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 4):

first you need to update the package list.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then you can use the apt to install kmplayer

```
sudo apt-get install kmplayer
```

if you still unable to get it. Then you have to enable canonical and universal repository in the updates and execute the above two commands.

Comment: -1 because this requires the Universe repository pocket but doesn't mention it.